# Ada: Access types and invalid completion with records

Tags: declaration, record, ada

I'm learning Ada and am using the book `Rendez-vous with Ada by Naiditch (1995)`. On page `385`, an example is given for package specification file with an incomplete type declaration:

```
package Restaurant_Linked_List is

   subtype Name_Type is String (1..20);
   type Restaurant_Record is private;

   procedure Add_To_List (New_Entry: in Restaurant_Record);
   procedure Get (New_Restaurant: out Restaurant_Record);
   procedure Delete_From_List (Target: in Name_Type);
   procedure Search_List (Target: in Name_Type);
   procedure Output_List;

   private
      type Ethnicity is (Chinese, Japanese, French, Korean, Mexican, Italian, Jewish, American, German);
      subtype Price_Type is Float range 0.0 .. 150.0;
      type Restaurant_Record; -- incomplete type declaration
      type Restaurant_Pointer is access Restaurant_Record;
      type Restaurant_Record is -- complete type declaration
        record
           Name: Name_Type;
           Food: Ethnicity;
           Average_Price: Price_Type;
           Next: Restaurant_Pointer;
        end record;

end Restaurant_Linked_List;
```

However on compilation of this primary unit even with the `-gnat95` switch, I get the error message:

**15:11 invalid completion of private type "Restaurant_Record" defined at line 4**

where line 15 is the line:  type Restaurant_Record; -- incomplete type declaration.

Naiditch proposed the above workaround to have the pointer (`Restaurant_Pointer`) to be a component of the very type of object that it can point to as written on page `384` in the book.

So how to fix the above code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The declaration at line 4 is already enough to allow you to declare `Restaurant_Pointer`. So just delete line 15.